# I can't select a column to specify a foreign key

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

What I want to do is very simple. Select a column(my foreign key) and then specify the referenced column.
But it seems like MySql workbench has a bug. I can´t select my foreign key. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image: My sql bug print screen here].

Mysql version > 8.0.12

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the SQL statements you have executed to generate the tables before. Also include the table structure you want to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to solve this?

General rule is that both columns has to be of same type and referenced column has to be indexed (eg. primary key).

If you share `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` for both tables, I can provide more info.

Here is list of all requirements from [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions):

> Parent and child tables must use the same storage engine, and they
> cannot be defined as temporary tables.
>
> Creating a foreign key constraint requires at least one of the SELECT,
> INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or REFERENCES privileges on the parent table
> as of 5.6.22.
>
> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
> have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
> the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
> nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
> must be the same.
>
> MySQL supports foreign key references between one column and another
> within a table. (A column cannot have a foreign key reference to
> itself.) In these cases, a “child table record” refers to a dependent
> record within the same table.
>
> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
> foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
> referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
> columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
> index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
> exist. This index might be silently dropped later if you create
> another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
> index_name, if given, is used as described previously.
>
> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
> columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
> where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order.
> Hidden columns that InnoDB adds to an index are also considered (see
> Section 14.6.2.1, “Clustered and Secondary Indexes”).
>
> NDB requires an explicit unique key (or primary key) on any column
> referenced as a foreign key. InnoDB does not, which is an extension of
> standard SQL.
>
> Index prefixes on foreign key columns are not supported. Consequently,
> BLOB and TEXT columns cannot be included in a foreign key because
> indexes on those columns must always include a prefix length.
>
> InnoDB does not currently support foreign keys for tables with
> user-defined partitioning. This includes both parent and child tables.
>
> This restriction does not apply for NDB tables that are partitioned by
> KEY or LINEAR KEY (the only user partitioning types supported by the
> NDB storage engine); these may have foreign key references or be the
> targets of such references.
>
> A table in a foreign key relationship cannot be altered to use another
> storage engine. To change the storage engine, you must drop any
> foreign key constraints first.